# how to recover password android with permission denied?

Tags: wi-fi

I get the following message:

```
adb: error: failed to copy '/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf' to '.\wpa_suppl
icant.conf': remote Permission denied
```

I can not copy nothing from my android to recover my password of mi wifi

Comment: Your device must be rooted to view the wpa_supplicant.conf file... Otherwise just log into the router and look what it is.

Answer (score 2):

You would need root access to access that sensitive file. If you don't have root access, then all efforts with adb would be futile. That file and the directory is owned by user wifi and group wifi, and because adb (user 2000) is neither a member of group wifi, nor that file has read permission for *others (users)*, you're at loss here.